# mySQL Workbench and concatenating outputs

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench and using sql to create a list of monthly outputs which have group by and order by components

Can I then export these all to a single cdv file adding to the bottom of each list?

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

do you mean `GROUP_CONCAT`? ex,

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CAtegoryID) CatIDList
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

will return

```
ID   CatIDList
===================
1    1,2,3
2    1,5
3    2,4,5,6
```

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)